# javascript dynamically create span and align text vertically : text stays at the bottom

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to generate an svg rectangle and a span, so that the text in the span element is vertically-aligned with the svg element. In declarative HTML+CSS, I managed to do it.
But I can't manage to do it by javascript.

Here my javascript code :

```
/* Svg creation
==============================*/
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg.setAttribute("width", 60);
svg.setAttribute("height", 60);


var square = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
square.setAttribute("x", 0);
square.setAttribute("y", 0);
square.setAttribute("width", 60);
square.setAttribute("height", 60);
square.setAttribute("fill", "red");

svg.appendChild(square);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

/* Span creation
==============================*/

var outerSpan = document.createElement("span");
outerSpan.style.height = "60px";
outerSpan.style.lineHeight = "60px";

var innerSpan = document.createElement("span");
innerSpan.style.display = "inline-block";
innerSpan.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
innerSpan.style.lineHeight = "1em";
innerSpan.textContent = "Red square";

outerSpan.appendChild(innerSpan);
document.body.appendChild(outerSpan);
```

Here [my codepen attempt](http://codepen.io/loloof64/pen/qOqMoo) : you can notice that the html+css code works, but not the javascript one, I mean, it shows everything, but not as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the vertical alignment of your `svg` element isn't `middle` itself; it's `baseline` (default). The `svg` element here is aligning itself to the baseline, which is the bottom of the text.

This can be resolved by simply specifying:

```
svg.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvmEdw).